# How can we send different request in body through string array in Beanshell (Jmeter)

Tags: beanshell

I am using below line for multiple data for different request, but through this code it will take last index of `imageString[i]`, and send every time same data .in beanshell sampler (Jmeter).

```
vars.put("imagData",    imageString[i]);
```

How can we send different request in body through string array?

```
    import java.io.*;
    int i;
        File file = new File("/home/sarvesh/Desktop/sgi/10");
    int filecount =  file.list().length;
    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    String[] imageString = new String[filecount];

          for ( i =0;i<filecount;i++) {

           File f = new File(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);     
           byte [] byteArray = new byte[(int) f.length()];
           fis.read(byteArray);
            imageString[i] = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);


                  vars.put("imagData",  imageString[i]);

        System.out.println("***********************************************");
        System.out.println("Base 64 conversion of  Image  : " + i + " ::" + imageString[i]);
        System.out.println("File Path     :                  " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("File Count     :                  " + filecount);
        System.out.println("***********************************************");

                }
```

Comment: show more relevant code so your question will be complete

Comment: i have add code which i am using